# Knockout observable array to dropdown

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

According to knockout documentation this should work, but I am still facing an empty dropdown list.
My skills are primarily not in the frontend, but I ended up here anyway.

### VIEW.aspx

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: EmployeeTypes, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'EmployeeTypeId', selectedOptions: SelectedEmployeeTypes, multiselect: SelectedEmployeeTypes, disable: isSaving" multiple="multiple"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

### VIEWMODEL .ts

```
 export class ViewModel
{
    EmployeeTypes: KnockoutObservableArray<EmployeeType> = ko.observableArray([]);
    ...
    async load() {
            var result = null;

            try {
                result = await this.service.get();
            } 
            catch (e) {
            }

            if (result) 
            {
                this.EmployeeTypes().map(result.EmployeeTypes, e => new EmployeeType(e));
            // Desperately tried following
            ////this.EmployeeTypes($.map(result.EmployeeTypes, e => new EmployeeType(e)));
            ////this.EmployeeTypes = ko.mapping.fromJS($.map(result.EmployeeTypes, e => new EmployeeType(e)))
            ////this.EmployeeTypes.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(result.EmployeeTypes.map(x => new EmployeeType(x))));
            ////this.EmployeeTypes = ko.mapping.toJS(result.EmployeeTypes.map(x => new EmployeeType(x)));
            ////this.EmployeeTypes = ko.unwrap($.map(result.EmployeeTypes, e => new EmployeeType(e)));
            ////this.EmployeeTypes = ko.observableArray([new EmployeeType({ Name: 'TESTNAME2', EmployeeTypeId: '1' })]);
            ////this.EmployeeTypes = ko.unwrap(result.EmployeeTypes.map(x => new EmployeeType(x)));
            }
    }
}
```

I've checked, my expected object exists in the result.EmployeeTypes
Also when I check then length of "this.EmployeeTypes" in Console I am getting 2 objects, as expected.

Result is just an empty dropdown.

If I initialize the knockoutObservableArray with a EmployeeType when declaring, it's visible in the dropdown.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: `.map` creates a new array, it would seem like you changing the type from `observableArray` to `array` using `map`.  To set values in KO you call you place the value inside the method call so I think your code should be `this.EmployeeTypes(result.map(EmployeeTypes, e => new EmployeeType(e)));`

Comment: Hi Erik, Thank you for you comment. You're right, but i also tried multiple way to call the method. I even tried to .unwrap the array.

Comment: Try with `this.EmployeeTypes(result.EmployeeTypes.map(e => new EmployeeType(e))`

Comment: Also, what is `multiselect` in your `data-bind`? Is that a custom binding?

Comment: Getting this error when using .map that way:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result.map is not a function**
multiselect is a custom component, but when i initialize the array with multiple values manually, i'll see the value correcly.
The multiselect makes it possible to check and uncheck multiple values.

Comment: Sorry, I updated that comment after a minute (It should be `result.EmployeeTypes.map` not `result.map`)

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` creates a new array, it would seem like you changing the type from an `observableArray` to an `array` using `map()`. To set values in KO you call the method with the the value inside as a parameter, so I think your code should be

```
this.EmployeeTypes(result.map(EmployeeTypes, e => new EmployeeType(e)));
```